# Passing querystring with login control in asp.net 4?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string

**Scenario:**

I am doing project in C# ASP.NET 4.

I have a page of question. When somebody clicks on question (ie a `Link Button`) he is redirected to page where user can give answer but first he needs to login. So I put `Login to Answer` button that redirects user to `GuestLogin.aspx` with question id like this :

```
protected void LoginToAnswwer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int qidrequest = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["qid"]);
    Response.Redirect("~/GuestLogin.aspx?qid=" + qidrequest);
    //This is working OK
}
```

And then when I am redirected to `GuestLogin.aspx`, I am putting below code in LoginButton of built in `Login Control`.

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int qidrequest = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["qid"]);
    Response.Redirect("QDisplay.aspx?qid=" + qidrequest);
}
```

Which is not working.

**Question:**

How to pass `querystring` with login button of built `login control` in asp.net 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a return URL to the login page, like this:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("/auth/login.aspx?return={0}", Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)));
```

In the login page, after authenticating the user:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["return"]);
```

Comment: It will allow you to redirect back to the answer page after logging in.

Comment: So, where should I put this : ?qid=" + qidrequest

Comment: From the answer page, redirect to the login page and send the answer page w/ the querystring in the return URL. That's what this is for: `Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)`

Comment: Both answer pages (before and after GuestLogin.aspx) are different. I have designed before one just for "Login to Answer" button and another for real work.

Comment: What exactly should be the syntax to perform the require task?

Comment: Assuming that "Login to Answer" is a `HyperLink` control, assign the above code the `NavigateUrl` property. All you're doing is passing a link back to the answer page to the login page, so once the user is authenticated you can redirect them back to the answer page.

Answer (score 1):

[Pass Parameters from One Page to Another Page using QueryString](http://doitdotnet.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/pass-parameters-from-one-page-to-another-page-using-querystring/) :

> //Set the Querystring parameters
>   Note:   Maximum length of the
>   string that can be passed through QueryString is 255.

```
string URL =“QueryString.aspx?Name=” + txtFirstName.Text + “&Address=” + txtAddress.Text + “&City=” + txtCity.Text ;  
 //After Setting the Querystring Paramter values Use Response.Redirect to navigate the page
 Response.Redirect(URL);
```

> In the Page Load Event of the Navigated
>   Page,You can access the querystring parameter values like below :

```
lblName.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();   
lblAddress.Text = Request.QueryString["Address"].ToString();   
lblCity.Text= Request.QueryString["City"].ToString();
```

> That's how you have to use QueryString for passing parameters